# FB.XFBML.parse(); won't load

Tags: javascript, facebook, drupal

I run this on Drupal platform. I'm trying to apply this to my [Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button). I have the SDK Javascript preprocessed, so it loads first before the [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/). And I have the FB.XFBML.parse put into the inline footer (also tried inline header).

On first page load, it loads the Share Button on the current items, but after calling the Ajax pager to load next 20 items, it loads them, but not the Share Button widgets, which means the FB.XFBML.parse doesn't go off.

As it says in [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/), I just included the `FB.XFBML.parse();` in my `<script></script>` to check entire page just in case.

Front-end [preview](http://i.imgur.com/gPMMfbu.gifv).

EDIT: I moved it from inline/footer to separate .js file and wrapped the container that contains the widgets to an `id="ajax-load-container"` and the .js looks like this `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('ajax-load-container'));`. But still not working.

Comment: By “inline footer,” you mean an element that gets replaced together with the rest of the content via the AJAX call? If so, you might need to enable script parsing in your AJAX call (because the default is that script elements loaded via AJAX are _not_ executed.)

Comment: Real problem is that I'm not sure what I'm doing since I don't really work with Javascript. So I'm just reading documentation and using given snippets.